# Facebook ads python sdk get_stats doesn't return "actions" field

Tags: python, facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

I can't get AdCampaign's get_stats() method to return the "actions" field. Snippet:

```
stats = list(ad_campaign.get_stats(fields=[
    'impressions',
    'spent',
    'clicks',
    'actions',
]))
print stats[0]
>>> <AdStats> {"clicks": 0, "impressions": 0, "spent": 0}
```

I have also tried to get the report on AdAccount, AdSet and AdGroup levels, but none of them had the "actions" field.

I'm assuming I have misconfigured my campaign, so here's a basic rundown:

- AdCampaign:

  - status: "PAUSED"
  - objective: "WEBSITE_CONVERSIONS"
- AdCampaign has one AdSet:

  - bid_type: "ABSOLUTE_OCPM"
  - bid_info: {'ACTIONS': 1}
  - promoted_object: {'pixel_id': <valid pixel id string>}
  - start_time: one month in the future
- AdSet has one AdGroup:

  - objective: "WEBSITE_CONVERSIONS"

I also queried the AdGroup object for conversion_specs, they are set and match defaults described in the doc.

Comment: It's not clear from this context what actual API call you're making - that SDK obscures the actual API call somewhat so can be difficult to debug if you're not familiar with the API - that said, are you sure there's actually 'actions' available in the response? have you looked at the reports in the Facebook UI to verify there's data there?

Comment: ad_campaign.get_stats() is making the following request:   
  
GET
/v2.2/6022145720101/stats?access_token=<valid access token>&appsecret_proof=<valid app secret proof>&summary=false&fields=impressions%2Cspent%2Cclicks%2Cactions      

I don't have immediate access to the UI, and I'm not really familiar with it, any clues on what I should look for? I'm expecting it to report 0 actions.

Comment: I don't think 'actions' is returned if its value when returned would be null / an empty array - many places in the Facebook SDK omit fields instead of providing empty fields

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to specify any fields for the `get_stats` method, but the reason you're not seeing any actions is probably because you don't have any. Try it against a campaign that you know people have taken action on. :)

Evan